# How to implement 3d kDTree build and search algorithm in c or c++?

Tags: c++, c, data-structures

How to implement 3d kDTree build and search algorithm in c or c++? I am wondering if we have a working code to follow

Answer (score 4):

I'd like to recommend you a two good presentations to start with:

- ["Introduction to k-d trees"](http://www.cs.umd.edu/class/spring2002/cmsc420-0401/pbasic.pdf)
- ["Lecture 6: Kd-trees and range trees"](http://www.cise.ufl.edu/class/cot5520fa09/CG_RangeKDtrees.pdf).

Both give all (basic ideas behind kd-trees, short visual examples and code snippets) you need to start writing your own implementation.

Update-19-10-2021: Resources are now longer public. Thanks to @Hari for posting new links down below in the comments.

Comment: Can I have a working code for the same. I want to run the program and trace few examples

Comment: +1 for link to excellent presentation of the concept. @iDev: Everything is crystal clear in the presentation, if you still are looking for a code then you are just a slacker.

Comment: The links are broken. The following link is related to the first link: https://www.cs.umd.edu/class/spring2021/cmsc420-0101/Slides/lect12-kd-dict-slides.pdf. The following are related to the second link: https://www.cs.umd.edu/class/fall2020/cmsc420-0201/Lects/lect16-kd-query.pdf, http://ima.udg.edu/~sellares/ComGeo/OrthogRangeSearch4Ms.pdf

Comment: Thanks, @Hari, for providing a proper links.
It seems the initial owner just closed the public access to their resources.

Answer (score 3):

I found the publications of [Vlastimil Havran](http://dcgi.felk.cvut.cz/home/havran/publications.html) very useful. His [Ph.d Thesis](http://dcgi.felk.cvut.cz/home/havran/DISSVH/phdthesis.html) gives a nice introduction to kd-trees and traversal algorithms. Further articles are about several improvements, e.g. how to construct kd-tree in [O(nlogn)](http://dcgi.felk.cvut.cz/home/havran/ARTICLES/ingo06rtKdtree.pdf). There are also a lot of implementations in different graphic libs. You should just google for it.

Answer (score 0):

For an example of a 3D kd-tree implementation in C, take a look at [kd3](https://github.com/shawnchin/kd3). It is not general purpose library and requires the input data to be in a specific form, but the ideas and approach should be transferable.

*Disclosure: I am the author of kd3.*

*Disclaimer: It was written as proof-of-concept code for an existing application and is therefore not as generic nor as well-tested as it should be. Bug reports/fixes are welcome.*